# how to find the logged in user in linux running oracle session

Tags: administration, oracle

i like to find out the logged in user to linux and running some session . we cannot use the os_user option as we all use sudo user before login to oracle. so how to find out the super user who logged into unix box and sudo to some other OS user and did sqlplus.

Can Some one help me

Answer (score 0):

The command `w` would list all the users currently logged into the system and also show what is being run

Here's a sample output of the command:
[image]

Screenshot taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_(Unix))

Comment: Thanks Runcy. But how i can link it which the db level session running in oracle .. As all users do Sudo, while trying to check from dba_audit_trail it is showing sudo user as OS user and in W output there are lot of user which make even more difficult to identify

Comment: In your "w" output, do you have IP addresses listed? Do you know the port no on which your application is running? If yes, then match these two details with "netstat -an | grep <port_no>". You should be able to able to see the list of IP addresses connecting to that application port and IP address from "w" will reveal the users. Hope it helps

Comment: I am not able to see ip address  in W output.. i am not checking only application related session ..

Comment: I am not able to see ip address  in W output.. i am not checking only application related session .. Even if a dba ran a command .. and when we get alert that it is running for long time ..we used to check who ran that command and it become difficult to find out. 

sorry for the earlier comment .. it got wrongly updated